# Long boot hang in Ubuntu 14.04LTS Guest OS in LXC debian 8 host

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart, lxc

I am running a debian 8 host and ubuntu 14.04LTS as a guest via LXC.

During the boot process the containers hang here:

```
root@i1:/var/lib/lxc# lxc-start -n mydeb
<4>init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (5) terminated with status 1
<4>init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
<4>init: hwclock main process (7) terminated with status 77
<4>init: ureadahead main process (8) terminated with status 5
<4>init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (15) terminated with status 1
<4>init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
* Starting Mount filesystems on boot   ...done.
[much detail deleted because 

 "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"]

* Starting configure virtual network devices   ...done.
```

for about 2 minutes after which they report

```
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS mydeb console
mydeb login: <4>init: setvtrgb main process (633) terminated with status 1
<4>init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
```

How does one debug upstart?

Answer (score 0):

You should check logs at `/var/lib/lxc/Your Container Name/var/log/upstart/`

- By default `/var/lib/lxc/` -  is a path where all containers are
  stored.
- `Your Container Name` - is a name of your container `mydeb`
- `/var/log/upstart/` - is a path for upstart logs